# Which settings add to ./configure

Tags: ffmpeg

I was able to build FFMPEG with ./configure --toolchain=msvc , but now i wanted to add all the other things:

```
./configure --target-os=win64 --arch=x86_64 --toolchain=msvc --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --
enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --
enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-
libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-
libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --
enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --
enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-
amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libgsm --
enable-librav1e --disable-w32threads --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-
cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-
libopenmpt --enable-amf  --enable-openal
```

i'm not sure if this is the way to do it, at the moment i'm getting this error:

```
ERROR: aom >= 1.0.0 not found using pkg-config
```

in the config.log i get this:

```
require_pkg_config libaom aom >= 1.0.0 aom/aom_codec.h aom_codec_version
check_pkg_config libaom aom >= 1.0.0 aom/aom_codec.h aom_codec_version
test_pkg_config libaom aom >= 1.0.0 aom/aom_codec.h aom_codec_version
pkg-config --exists --print-errors aom >= 1.0.0
Package aom was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `aom.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'aom' found
ERROR: aom >= 1.0.0 not found using pkg-config
```

I only need the photosensitivity filter and the lut3d filter, do i need to include all those things with the ./configure?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install libaom-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither photosensitivity nor the lut3d filter require any external dependencies. You may remove `--enable-libaom` and any similar blocking options.